# How to determine a count based on an associated table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Given two tables:

```
posts (id, title, published_at)
posts_meta_data (post_id, description, image_url)
```

All post records have an associated posts_meta_data row.

How can I determine the average # of posts that have images? For example, if in my database there are 100 posts in my database, and 20 of those have image_url defined (ie not null).. the query should return 20/100 = 20%.

Comment: Can a post have more than one image link?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping, I understood your question correctly.

You can check below query.

```
select count(b.image_url) / count(a.id)
from posts a
inner join posts_meta_data b
    on a.id = b.post_id;
```

Comment: @Tim Biegelesen I didn't used left join because as mentioned in the question `All post records have an associated posts_meta_data row`. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Take the distinct count of posts having an image URL divided by the total count of posts:

```
SELECT
    100.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p_meta.url IS NOT NULL THEN p_meta.post_id END) /
        COUNT(p_meta.post_id) AS pct
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN posts_meta_data p_meta
    ON p.id = p_meta.post_id;
```

The reason I use a roundabout way to calculate the percentage of posts which do have an image URL is that the join could potentially result in a post record mapping to more than one meta record.  But, there is guaranteed to be only one non matching record.

Comment: @AnApprentice . . . This answer is not correct.  It calculates a ratio against the number of *metadata* rows, not of posts.

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If all posts have metadata, you don't need a `join`.  If there is at most one image:

```
select ( count( (pm.url is not null) ) / 
         count(distinct pm.post_id)
       ) as ratio
from posts_meta_data pm;
```

Or alternatively:

```
select count(pm.post_id) / count(*) as ratio
from posts p
left join posts_metadata pm
    on pm.post_id = p.id and
       pm.url is not null
```

If there can be more than one image, then:

```
select ( count(distinct case when pm.url is not null then pm.post_id end ) /
         count(distinct pm.post_id)
       ) as ratio
from posts_meta_data pm;
```

Comment: this is great but I needed to add a WHERE clause posts.published_at IS NOT NULL